# SQL - Find missing int values in mostly ordered sequential series

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I manage a message based system in which a sequence of unique integer ids will be entirely represented at the end of the day, though they will not necessarily arrive in order.

I am looking for help in finding missing ids in this series using SQL.  If my column values are something like the below, how can I find which ids I am missing in this sequence, in this case `6`?

The sequence will begin and end at an arbitrary point each day, so min and max would differ upon each run. Coming from a Perl background I through some regex in there.

```
ids
1
2
3
5
4
7
9
8
10
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: We run oracle

Edit2: Thanks all.  I'll be running through your solutions next week in the office.

Edit3:  I settled for the time being on something like the below, with ORIG_ID being the original id column and MY_TABLE being the source table.  In looking closer at my data, there are a variety of cases beyond just number data in a string.  In some cases there is a prefix or suffix of non-numeric characters.  In others, there are dashes or spaces intermixed into the numeric id.  Beyond this, ids periodically appear multiple times, so I included distinct.

I would appreciate any further input, specifically in regard to the best route of stripping out non-numeric characters.

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN NUMERIC_ID + 1 = NEXT_ID - 1
         THEN TO_CHAR( NUMERIC_ID + 1 )
      ELSE TO_CHAR( NUMERIC_ID + 1 ) || '-' || TO_CHAR( NEXT_ID - 1 )
   END
   MISSING_SEQUENCES
   FROM
   (
      SELECT
         NUMERIC_ID,
         LEAD (NUMERIC_ID, 1, NULL)
            OVER 
            (
               ORDER BY
                 NUMERIC_ID
                 ASC
            )
            AS NEXT_ID
         FROM 
         (
             SELECT
                DISTINCT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_REPLACE(ORIG_ID,'[^[:digit:]]','') ) 
                AS NUMERIC_ID
             FROM MY_TABLE
         )
    ) WHERE NEXT_ID != NUMERIC_ID + 1
```

Comment: I read the title as "SELECT * FROM FOO MOSTLY ORDER BY..."

Comment: You should add a tag for the brand of RDBMS you're using, e.g. sql-server, oracle, postgresql, mysql, etc.

Comment: How would you know that id=11 and id=0 aren't missing?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily, but this is more of a sanity check to trigger further investigation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been there.

**`FOR ORACLE:`**

I found this **extremely useful** query on the net a while ago and noted down, however I don't remember the site now, you may search for **`"GAP ANALYSIS"`** on Google.

```
SELECT   CASE
             WHEN ids + 1 = lead_no - 1 THEN TO_CHAR (ids +1)
          ELSE TO_CHAR (ids + 1) || '-' || TO_CHAR (lead_no - 1)
         END
             Missing_track_no
   FROM   (SELECT   ids,
                    LEAD (ids, 1, NULL)
                     OVER (ORDER BY ids ASC)
                        lead_no
             FROM   YOURTABLE
             )
   WHERE   lead_no != ids + 1
```

**Here, the result is:**

```
MISSING _TRACK_NO
-----------------
       6
```

**If there were multiple gaps,say 2,6,7,9 then it would be:**

```
MISSING _TRACK_NO
-----------------
        2
       6-7
        9
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll have to give it a when I'm back in the office. Thanks.

Comment: One small extra wrinkle.  In looking closer, despite the data being numberic, the ids column is varchar2.  I assume I can use TO_NUMBER for references to ids in the above?

Comment: Try it and share your result. The '-' wont be stored in numeric column.

Comment: TO_NUMBER fit the majority of my use cases.  I had a couple situations where the numeric id was prefixed or suffixed by a variety of letter characters.  I ran a regex on the id before using TO_NUMBER to convert it.  This works, though I'm not sure if a REGEX_REPLACE is the best route for such a task.

Comment: I don't know your overall system, so I am not able to give you a %100 solution. However, you may try `ELSE TO_CHAR (ids + 1) || TO_CHAR (lead_no - 1)`. Instead of adding a '-'. So you won't need to use regex. It will be `67` instead of `6-7`. I think it is not hard to understand the missing ones are 6 & 7. But again, it is your choice.

Answer (score 4):

This is sometimes called an exclusion join.  That is, try to do a join and return only rows where there is no match.

```
SELECT t1.value-1
FROM ThisTable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ThisTable AS t2
  ON t1.id = t2.value+1
WHERE t2.value IS NULL
```

Note this will always report at least one row, which will be the MIN `value`.

Also, if there are gaps of two or more numbers, it will only report one missing value.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I could do the same for with value + 1 to find the other bound of my missing ranges.  Is there any way to do this in a single query and maybe concat chars to the end of each type of bound to distinguish them?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't state your DBMS, so I'm assuming PostgreSQL:

```
select aid as missing_id
from generate_series( (select min(id) from message), (select max(id) from message)) as aid
  left join message m on m.id = aid
where m.id is null;
```

This will report any missing value in a sequence between the minimum and maximum id in your table (including gaps that are bigger than one)

```
psql (9.1.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> select * from message;
 id
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  7
  8
  9
 11
 14
(10 rows)


postgres=> select aid as missing_id
postgres-> from generate_series( (select min(id) from message), (select max(id) from message)) as aid
postgres->   left join message m on m.id = aid
postgres-> where m.id is null;
 missing_id
------------
          6
         10
         12
         13
(4 rows)
postgres=>
```

Comment: Thaaaanks! Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I applied it in mysql, it worked ..

```
mysql> select * from sequence;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      4 |
|      6 |
|      7 |
|      8 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.number - 1 FROM sequence AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN sequence AS t2 O
N t1.number = t2.number +1 WHERE t2.number IS NULL;
+---------------+
| t1.number - 1 |
+---------------+
|             0 |
|             3 |
|             5 |
+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET search_path='tmp';

DROP table tmp.table_name CASCADE;
CREATE table tmp.table_name ( num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
-- make some data
INSERT INTO tmp.table_name(num) SELECT generate_series(1,20);
-- create some gaps
DELETE FROM tmp.table_name WHERE random() < 0.3 ;

SELECT * FROM table_name;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH zbot AS (
    SELECT 1+tn.num  AS num
    FROM table_name tn
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table_name nx
        WHERE nx.num = tn.num+1
        )
    )
, ztop AS (
    SELECT -1+tn.num  AS num
    FROM table_name tn
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table_name nx
        WHERE nx.num = tn.num-1
        )
    )
SELECT zbot.num AS bot
    ,ztop.num AS top
FROM zbot, ztop
WHERE zbot.num <= ztop.num
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM table_name nx
    WHERE nx.num >= zbot.num
    AND nx.num <= ztop.num
    )
ORDER BY bot,top
    ;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 20
DELETE 9
 num 
-----
   1
   2
   6
   7
  10
  11
  13
  14
  15
  18
  19
(11 rows)

 bot | top 
-----+-----
   3 |   5
   8 |   9
  12 |  12
  16 |  17
(4 rows)
```

Note: a recursive CTE is also possible (and probably shorter).

UPDATE: here comes the recursive CTE ...:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT 1+num AS num
    FROM table_name t0
    UNION
    SELECT 1+num FROM tree tt
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM table_name xt
        WHERE xt.num > tt.num
        )
    )
SELECT * FROM tree
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_name nx
    WHERE nx.num = tree.num
    )
ORDER BY num
    ;
```

Results: (same data)

```
 num 
-----
   3
   4
   5
   8
   9
  12
  16
  17
  20
 (9 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_key, next_student_key
      from (
    select student_key, lead(student_key) over (order by student_key) next_fed_cls_prgrm_key
      from student_table
           )
where student_key <> next_student_key-1;
```